# How to do both filtering and grouping listview from SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, filtering, grouping

How do I get my `listview` to do both grouping and filtering because I can only get it to do one of the thing at once. I had tried almost everything I could but none of it worked. when i remove

```
 public string SelectedParam { get { return _selectedParam; } set { _selectedParam = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParam");
        if (_selectedParam == "Krydsmål") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; } } }
```

then the grouping works but the filtering doesn't

i wonder if i can use the sql for filling instead for both filling and filtering and then get the listview to do the filtering like you can do with manualy added items

My combobox for filtering:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Krydsmålbox" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="12" 
Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate2}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectedValuePath="Krydsmålene"
SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                  AncestorType={x:Type Window}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Height="40" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="586,42,379,0"/>
```

Listview

```
 <ListView x:Name="hjuldata" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Foreground="#FF00FB0B"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="#FF303030" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="-160,242,11,22" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="3" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle2}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="576">
 <ListView.View>
 <GridView>
 <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEAEAEA"/>
 <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
 </Style>
 </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
 <GridViewColumn Header="" >
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
 <Image Source="{Binding Billed, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
 </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
 <GridViewColumn Header="Model" Width="140" >
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
 <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Model}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
 </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
 <GridViewColumn Header="Årgang" Width="100">
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
 <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Årgang}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
 </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
 <GridViewColumn Header="Motor Type" Width="150" >
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
 <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding [Motor Type]}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
 </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
 <GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Krydsmålet}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
  </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Centerhul}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
  </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn Header="ET" Width="auto">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding ET}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
  </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn Header="Bolter" Width="100">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Bolter}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
  </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn Header="Dæk" Width="300">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Dæk}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
  </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn Header="Fælge" Width="200">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Fælge}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
  </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
  </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
```

grouping style

```
  <ListView.GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
  <ControlTemplate>
  <Expander IsExpanded="False"  BorderBrush="#FFEAEAEA" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" >
 <Expander.Header>
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding Items}">
 <Image Source="{Binding Billed, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Mærke}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Krydsmålene}"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFBFB00" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,150,0" TextAlignment="Center" />
 </StackPanel>
 </Expander.Header>
 <ItemsPresenter />
 </Expander>
 </ControlTemplate>
 </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
 </Style>
 </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
 </GroupStyle>
 </ListView.GroupStyle>
 </ListView>
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _selectedParam;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindData();
        ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);
        dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Mærke"));

    }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string SelectedParam { get { return _selectedParam; } set { _selectedParam = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParam");
    if (_selectedParam == "Krydsmål") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; } } }

    private void BindData()
    {
        hjuldata.ItemsSource = Kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
    public DataSet Kategori()
    {

        Data = @"Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmålet, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene from Data.Hjuldata P  inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID ORDER BY ps.Mærket";
        //SQL statement to fetch entries from Hjuldata
        DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

        //Open SQL Connection
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
        {
            conn.Open();

            //Initialize command object                
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
            {                
                SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                //Fill the result set

                adapters.Fill(dsdata);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return dsdata;
    }

    public DataSet FilterKategori()
    {
        Data = @"Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmålet, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene from Data.Hjuldata P  inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID WHERE Krydsmålet = @param1";

        //SQL statement to fetch entries from products
        DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

        //Open SQL Connection
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
        {
            conn.Open();

            //Initialize command object

            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", SelectedParam);
                SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //Fill the result set
                adapters.Fill(dsdata);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }  
        return dsdata;
    }
```

Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: Looks like that your listview is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is something you should read
[How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_4)

i had tested that one and it works with your datastructure and you dont have to do anything with your filtering only change out the grouping part and colectionview

Comment: awesome that worked now i just have to figure out if there is a way i can do it without using the button for grouping and ungrouping just so they are always grouped

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are using the ADO.NET data view abstraction rather than the WPF data view abstraction which should be easier to use. In WPF when you bind a collection or `DataTable` to an `ItemsControl` a data view object is created that basically serves as a layer over your collection or `DataTable`. By doing this you can potentially have the same collection bound to multiple `ItemsControls` but have different "views" of that data by having different filtering and grouping for the two distinct data views that are created for that same collection.

In your case you are binding to a `DataTable` which is messier than binding just to a collection that implements `IList`. For `DataTable` there is a `DataView` class that is part of ADO.NET that your WPF data view will basically serve as a layer over and this `DataView` is more limited in functionality (this ADO.NET `DataView` is what you are using in your code currently).

Either way, to get the WPF data view you just need to ask the `ItemsSource` for it like so:

```
ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myListView.ItemsSource);
```

Now you will want to cast the `ICollectionView` to something more useful for setting the filter and grouping. In your case you have a `DataTable` so you will want to cast that to a `BindingListCollectionView`. Unfortunately this is more limited than the data view you would get for an `IList` (which is a `ListCollectionView`), but you have a `DataTable` so we will just roll with it for now (I always go with `IList` so I have never actually implemented a `DataTable` binding in production before).

The `BindingListCollectionView` doesn't have an operational `Filter` property so you have to use its `CustomFilter` property to specify the partial SQL that you want to use to filter your collection (basically what you would have put in a `WHERE` clause). As far as grouping goes I haven't ever used it on a `DataTable` binding but I would hope it just works by updating `GroupDescriptions` on the data view.

So basically in summary I would grab the WPF data view abstraction rather than the ADO.NET data view abstraction that you are currently using and set the filter and grouping on that. Also I would recommend just bringing in your data as an `IList` or else converting it to an `IList` since those are easier to work with in WPF.

Comment: `Dataview ` doesn't support grouping 
and i alredy use `ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);`

and using `hjuldata.ItemsSource = Kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;`  to call it

Comment: Right. The thing is that you want to set both the Filter and Group on that ICollectionView that you get back (I explained how to do this for a DataTable source in my post). When you set the filtered data in your code you are setting the ItemsSource to a whole other ADO.NET DataView which is likely blowing away the ICollectionView that was there which had the grouping set on it. Basically you should be doing your filtering directly on the ICollectionView and if you update the ItemsSource you should reset the grouping and filter.

Comment: i actualy thougth about that by using  `dataView.Filter = SelectedParam;`  but unfortunately `SelectedParam ` is a string and not a object  or using `dataView.Filter = OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParam"); ` but thats a void and so i thougth that i could make my table as a class for that but then i had another problem because i using 2 tables

Comment: That won't work, because the ICollectionView that comes back from a source that is a DataTable is a BindingListCollectionView, and the Filter property on that doesn't do anything (calling the CanFilter property on the ICollectionView that you get back will return false). You have to cast your ICollectionView to a BindingListCollectionView and then use the CustomFilter property as described in my answer. As I mentioned before it is easier to use an IList as the source since the Filter property will just work out of the box for that.

Comment: do you have a link to a documentation or guide to that so i can get a more clear view on how to do that

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinglistcollectionview.customfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) gives good info and links. Also an older version of the [Pro WPF book](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2008-Presentation-Professionals/dp/1590599551/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1463745928&sr=1-1&keywords=pro+wpf+3.5) that I have gives a detailed description starting at the end of page 578 in the section titled *Filtering the DataTable*. To reinforce my conclusion though, if you can convert to an IList do so, that way you don't have to worry about all this.